# Not equal != Google App script does not work

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, comparison

I'm trying to do a simple script to ask for a password at the moment to open a spreadsheet, but I'm having trouble with the not equal != comparison, does anybody have any idea of this error, find the code below:

```js
function onOpen(e) {
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kMjlxxWPe8sRwuP5V3Dd_B4wyx642rssGCX06nG");
  var x = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Ingresa contraseña por favor");

  var pass = 123;
  do{   
    var x = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Ingresa contraseña por favor");
  }
  while( x != pass){

}
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Contraseña correcta");
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information on what the error is and what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do more research before asking questions - `ui#prompt` returns a [`PromptResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response), not a string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function test_propmt() {    
  var pass = '123'; // response is a text
  var x;
  while( x != pass){   
    // prompt is an object. To get text:
    x = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Ingresa contraseña por favor").getResponseText();
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Contraseña correcta");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> replace your code into this

```
do{ 
    // remove 'var'
    x = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Ingresa contraseña por favor");
  }
  while( x != pass)
```

**remove "var" inside "do" block , do not declare local variable in "do" block**